# Laravel - How to Display both count and percentage (%) in chartjs pie chart

Tags: laravel, chart.js

In my Laravel-5.8, I have used chartjs to display total male and female counts (total number of male and female)

as shown below:

Controller:

```
public function report()
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;

$gender_record = HrEmployee::selectRaw('count(gender_id) as count,gender_id, if (gender_id = 1, "Male", "Female") as gender')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->groupBy('gender_id')->get();        
$gender_data = [];

foreach($gender_record as $row) {
   $gender_data['gender_label'][] = $row->gender;
   $gender_data['gender_data'][] = (int) $row->count;
 }

 $gender_data['gender_chart_data'] = json_encode($gender_data);    

    return view('report-default', $gender_data);       
}
```

view

```
   <div class="card-body">
      <canvas id="empGender" style="min-height: 250px; height: 250px; max-height: 250px; max-width: 100%;"></canvas>
   </div>

    <script src="{{ asset('theme/adminlte3/plugins/chart.js/Chart.min.js') }}"></script>

   <script>
     $(function () {
      /* ChartJS
       * -------
       * Charts using ChartJS
       */

   //-------------
   //- GENDER-EMPLOYEE CHART -
   //-------------
   // Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
  var genderData = JSON.parse(`<?php echo $gender_chart_data; ?>`);
  var genderChartCanvas = $('#empGender').get(0).getContext('2d')
  var genderData        = {

  labels: genderData.gender_label,
    datasets: [
    {
    data: genderData.gender_data,
      backgroundColor : [
            '#f56954', 
            '#00a65a', 
            '#f39c12', 
            '#00c0ef',               
      ],
            borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        ],
        borderWidth: 1          
     }  
  ]
 }
 var genderOptions     = {
    maintainAspectRatio : true,
    responsive : true,
    cutoutPercentage: 80,

 }
 //Create pie or douhnut chart
  var genderChart = new Chart(genderChartCanvas, {
   type: 'doughnut',
   data: genderData,
   options: genderOptions      
   })

   })   
   </script>
```

[image: Gender Donut Chart]

What I have as shown above only displays Total counts per Gender as shown above.

How do I make it also to include the percentage per Gender?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by defining a [tooltip label callback](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#label-callback) function as follows.

```
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    label: (tooltipItem, data) => {
      var value = data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index];
      var total = data.datasets[0].data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
      var pct = 100 / total * value;
      var pctRounded = Math.round(pct * 10) / 10;
      return value + ' (' + pctRounded + '%)';
    }
  }
}
```

Please have a look at below runnable code snippet.

```js
new Chart('empGender', {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ['Male', 'Female'],
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: ['#f56954', '#00a65a'],
      borderColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)', 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'],
      data: [17, 7],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    responsive: true,
    cutoutPercentage: 80,
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: (tooltipItem, data) => {
          var value = data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index];
          var total = data.datasets[0].data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
          var pct = 100 / total * value;
          var pctRounded = Math.round(pct * 10) / 10;
          return value + ' (' + pctRounded + '%)';
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="empGender" height="100"></canvas>
```